Use Microsoft Georgia font
How can I use the Microsoft Georgia font in LaTeX? I have tried below:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{georgia}

\begin{document}
    One two \textbf{three} \textit{four}.
\end{document}

But it gives me the error:
"Font T1/georgia/m/n/10=recGEORGIA at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.\n<to be read again>"

I want to use the font for the headers for the sections in my document.
edit: I want to use Trebuchet MS as well in my doucment for the main text. How can I use both in the same document?

Using the LuaLaTeX engine (I invite to read the @David Carlisle's comment) and sectsty package:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}  % Use fontspec for system fonts
% Set Georgia as the main font
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\fontspec{Georgia}}  % Georgia font to section headings

\begin{document}
\chapter{Earth and Sun}
This is a first text in the Georgia font.
\section{Mars and Moon}
This is a second text in the Georgia font.
\end{document}


Addendum after the edit of the OP:

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}  % Use fontspec for system fonts
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\fontspec{Trebuchet MS}}  
\begin{document}
\chapter{Earth and Sun}
This is a first text in the Georgia font.
\section{Mars and Moon}
This is a second text in Trebuchet MS for section headings.
\end{document}


better to use lualatex, unless there is a pressing requirement to use xelatex (but your example is good for both)

@DavidCarlisle Thank you very much. Before I use always XeLaTeX and to the end LuaLaTeX.

xetex has serious issues supporting accessible pdf, and is essentially unsupported, it is better to recommend luatex to new users.

Thanks. Is there not possiblity to use it with pdflatex?

@KGB91 For my humble opinion, no:  pdfLaTeX  doesn't support system fonts like Georgia natively via the fontspec package.

@Sebastiano Okay, the problem is that I want to use trebuchet as well and I can only do that by using fontenc together with \pdfmapfile{+winfonts.map}

@KGB91 I don't know if it's possible. Don't worry, remove the green check . I never have seen a mix of LuaLaTeX + pdfLaTeX.

@KGB91 You can do it with pdflatex, but it is not easy or fast. I don't recommend it. If you are using fonts which are truetype (or opentype), it is significantly easier to use lualatex. If you are insistent on pdflatex, you will need (at a minimum) to create TFM files for each font, a font definition file (probably one per font), and a map file (possibly others, I am working from memory here on what's needed). If you really, really, want to do that, open a new question about how. In short, though: Use lualatex.

@KGB91 just use \setmainfont{Trebuchet MS} rather than Georgia, and then specify Georgia as the font to use for headings

@KGB91 possible? yes. do you want to do it? almost certainly, no. I might do it. but you need to learn a bunch of stuff (or pay somebody who already knows that bunch of stuff) to create good quality support files. and the fonts need a licence permitting conversion or full embedding. if you just want to use it for headings and the licence allows it, 'simple' use of autoinst or fontinst might be enough. but the 'simple' is far more complicated than using luatex.

@Sebastiano. Thanks for the updated awnser, now everthinhg is working perfectly.
